# Solr installation in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, tar, aws, solr

I am trying to unzip solr in ubuntu 14.04 as below:

```
ubuntu@ip-:~/solr$ ls
solr-­6.2.0.tgz

ubuntu@ip-:~/solr$ tar xzf solr-6.2.0.tgz
tar (child): solr-6.2.0.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

ubuntu@ip-:~/solr$ tar xf solr-6.2.0.tgz
tar: solr-6.2.0.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Kindly advise!

Comment: `solr-6.2.0.tgz` (with a hyphen) is not the same as `solr­6.2.0.tgz`

Comment: Use tab completion next time to avoid typos like this.

Comment: Try the following: `find $HOME -name solr-6.2.0.tgz  ` This will locate the file and then it should be an easy matter to open it...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the filename is **solr­6.2.0.tgz**, but you're trying to unpack **solr-6.2.0.tgz**.

Comment: I have typed it wrong in the question,corrected it above.

Comment: @AnuragD Please don't make typos like that... they waste everybody's time.

Comment: @edwinksl ok! but any clue for the above error?